# CALayer on CATiledLayer, drawLayer:inContext never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

i have a UIView which display a PDF page using CATiledLayer, now i want to add another CALayer on TiledLayer to draw some annots, Please see the code below.

```
    + (Class)layerClass
    {
        return [TiledLayer class];
    }

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
       TiledLayer *tiledLayer = (id)self.layer;
        tiledLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        NSAssert([tiledLayer isKindOfClass:[TiledLayer class]], @"self.layer must be CATiledLayer");

        drawingLayer = [CALayer layer];
        drawingLayer.frame = frame;
        //its crashing if set the delegate, if not drawLayer is never called.
        [drawingLayer setDelegate:self];
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.drawingLayer];

    }

}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if(layer == [self layer])
   {
     [self drawPDFPage];
     [drawingLayer setNeedsDisplay];
   }
   else if(layer == drawingLayer)
   {
     //this one is never called.
     [self drawSomethinghere];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIView uses the existence of -drawRect: to determine if it should allow its CALayer to be invalidated, which would then lead to the layer creating a backing store and -drawLayer:inContext: being called.

Implementing an empty -drawRect: method allows UIKit to continue to implement this logic, while doing the real drawing work inside of -drawLayer:inContext:.

Just add to you class implementation:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{

}
```

And your drawLayer method should work.